# Attempting to save an edited image to my local computer using AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am looking to save an image to my computer, so far I have the code below which displays an image with text inserted above. I'm unsure of how to save the image to my local machine, could someone help point me in the direction.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Sample</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <style>
                .container {
                position: relative;
                text-align: center;
                color: white;
                }
                .centered {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                }
            </style>
        <div ng-app= "myapp" ng-controller = "connection">
           Enter The Text :
            <input type="text" ng-model= "Username" name="Username">
            <button ng-click="submit(Username)" >Save</button><br><br>
            <div class="container">
            <img src="DHONI.jpg" >
            <div class="centered">{{Username}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        var App = angular.module("myapp",[])
        App.controller ('connection',function ($scope){
        $scope.submit= submit;
        function submit(Username){
            $scope.name = Username;
        }
        });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can try to use canvas for this type of requirement, very easy in that,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using canvas.Please replace {BASE64IMAGE} with your image as base64.
run the code in local system.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Sample</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://files.codepedia.info/files/uploads/iScripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
        <style>
            .ctn {
                position: relative;
            }

            .u-name {
                    position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 25%;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            var App = angular.module("myapp", [])
            App.controller('connection', function ($scope) {
                $scope.submit = submit;

                function submit(Username) {
                    $scope.name = Username;
                    var element = $("#ImageContent"); 
                    html2canvas(element, {
                        onrendered: function (canvas) {
                            console.log(canvas);
                            var imgageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                            // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
                            var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
                            $("#ImageDownload").attr("download", Username+".png").attr("href", newData);
                            document.getElementById('ImageDownload').click();
                        }
                    });

                }
            });

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="connection">
            <div class="container">
                <form> <br> Enter The Text :
                    <input type="text" ng-model="Username" name="Username">
                    <button ng-click="submit(Username)" >Submit</button>
                    <br>
                    <div id="ImageContent">
                        <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,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'/>
                        <div class="u-name">{{Username}}</div>
                </div>
                    <a id="ImageDownload" href="" ></a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```